# How to create a simple docker container that will be periodically sending curl requests?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following standalone docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  feed_activator:
    container_name: feed_activator
    image: docker
    volumes: [ "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" ]
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "apk --no-cache add curl", "while true; do sleep 60; curl 'https://google.com'; done" ]
    restart: "always"
```

what I would expect it to do is to simply install curl and send a GET request to https://google.com every minute.

What happens instead is

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing brotli-libs (1.0.9-r3)
(2/4) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.42.0-r1)
(3/4) Installing libcurl (7.78.0-r0)
(4/4) Installing curl (7.78.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.32.1-r6.trigger
OK: 13 MiB in 24 packages
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: 13 MiB in 24 packages
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: 13 MiB in 24 packages
```

where the

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: 13 MiB in 24 packages
```

part is repeating endlessly and the container is in a restarting state.
What do I have to do for it to function correctly? Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't try to write a "standalone" Compose file like this.  Every time you restart the process, it will need to reinstall the Alpine package dependencies; that's slow and wasteful and doesn't scale beyond trivial examples.  This setup of writing a complex `command:` is also tricky to get right.

The first thing I'd do is to write an ordinary shell script that does what you want:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# curl-periodically.sh
while true
do
  sleep 60
  curl 'https://google.com'
done
```

You can run this locally, outside Docker, to make sure it does what you want.

```sh
chmod +x curl-periodically.sh
./curl-periodicially.sh
```

You can then write a Dockerfile to turn your program into a runnable Docker image.  This file should be named exactly `Dockerfile`.

```sh
FROM alpine

# Set up OS-level dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache add curl

# Copy the application in
WORKDIR /app
COPY curl-periodically.sh .

# Explain what to do when a container starts
CMD ["./curl-periodically.sh"]
```

Now your Compose setup just needs to explain that this image needs to be built.  You do not need to write a complex `sh -c` command or bind-mount anything.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  feed_activator:
    build: .
    restart: always
```

(Avoid bind-mounting the Docker socket into a container, using the Docker Hub `docker` image, and otherwise trying to manipulate containers from other containers: you can trivially root the entire host this way, and it makes your application unnecessarily tied to Docker.  Something that depends on `docker` commands might not even run in other container systems like Kubernetes.  This example doesn't seem to need it at all and I've not included it.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to run all in one command like so

```
command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "apk --no-cache add curl; while true; do sleep 60; curl 'https://google.com'; done" ]
```

note the
`...url", "while...`  to  `...url; while...` difference